# Reset.CSS: hyperlinks "hover" if cursor is horizontally-adjacent

Tags: css, hyperlink, reset

I'm using Eric Meyer's Reset CSS, and all hyperlinks "hover" (you know, act like the cursor is hovering over them) if the cursor is horizontally-adjacent to said hyperlinks, not necessarily hovering over the text of the hyperlinks themselves.

This is probably the doing of the Reset CSS, however I am not sure how to fix this, I'd figure it out eventually, but I'm hoping someone here can provide a quick fix.

Also, where should the Reset.CSS be in relation to my main.CSS?  Should it be on the line above or the line below main.CSS for priority in the HTML file?  That might be an issue as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Resets always go first. Your CSS second, or else you end up resetting your own rules.

Comment: can you please show an example?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to reset your styles *first*, using reset.css at the very top of everything else, and then add you own styles.

The basic rest.css from Eric Meyer does not touch anchors (a) in any way, so I suspect your own code (or browser) for strange mouseover-behaviour. Use your browsers developer tools (usually opened up by pressing F12) and check the styles applied to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, as far as I know this can be caused in two cases.

First, if your markup is like this `<a><li>some hyperlink</li><a>`, and your CSS is like this:

```
a:hover{
    ....
}
```

OR

your markup is like this `<li><a>some hyperlink</a></li>` <- this is correct way but your CSS is like this:

```
li:hover{
   ...
}
```

so you might want to check your markup, I don't think so that this is caused by your CSS reset.